# twif to tpl opencart 2.3.0.2

Tags: php, twig, opencart2.3

Hi I have a module that is for 2.3.0.2 but it has some code written for twig and it is not working for 2.3.0.2, can any one help to get this code back to tpl.

```
product['model']<a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="refudt(this)"  data- 
type="model" data-pid="product['product_id']"> (?)</a>

{{ product.price }} <a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="refudt(this)"  data- 
type="price" data-pid="{{ product.product_id }}"> (?)</a>

 {{ product.name }}<a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="refudt(this)"  data- 
 type="name" data-pid="{{ product.product_id }}"> (?)</a></a>

{{ product.quantity }}<a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="refudt(this)"  
data-type="quantity" data-pid="{{ product.product_id }}"> (?)</a>

{{ total.text }}<a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="refudt(this)"  data- 
type="total" data-pid="{{total.order_total_id}}"> (?)</a>
```

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to understand your question. See [ask]. What do you want to do, what have you tried, and what results did you get. Remember that hiding a question in the title is a good way for few people to understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

this part not a TWIG and not php (tpl)

```
product['model']<a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="refudt(this)"  data- 
    type="model" data-pid="product['product_id']"> (?)</a>
```

the last part should look like this:

```
<?php echo $product['price']; ?> <a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="refudt(this)"  data- 
type="price" data-pid="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>"> (?)</a>

 <?php echo $product['name']; ?><a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="refudt(this)"  data- 
 type="name" data-pid="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>"> (?)</a></a>

<?php echo $product['quantity']; ?><a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="refudt(this)"  
data-type="quantity" data-pid="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>"> (?)</a>

<?php echo $total['text']; ?><a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="refudt(this)"  data- 
type="total" data-pid="<?php echo $total['order_total_id']; ?>"> (?)</a>
```

You should understand I hope...